# How to enable debug logging for Tomcat native/APR SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I'm using Tomcat "native" APR to provide SSL.  My Connector looks like:

```
<Connector port="8443"  
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    SSLVerifyClient="require"
    SSLCertificateFile="..." 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="..." 
    SSLPassword="..."
    SSLCACertificateFile="..."
    maxThreads="200" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"/>
```

I'm having trouble with the APR side refusing certificates and I want to debug this.  How can I enable debug output (logging) for the SSL session on the Tomcat/APR side?  Adding "javax.net.debug=ssl" doesn't work, of course, since the APR binary is handling SSL, not Java.

I do have the javax.net.debug=ssl output on my client side, but that's not enough info since the error is being sent from the server (Tomcat/APR).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in conf/logging.properties

```
org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE
```

If you console logging is setup, then you should get a heap of output to the catalina.out file.

Comment: For net related message, the logging of the `org.apache.tomcat.net` package must be increased.