# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH with signed certificate in Tomcat 8.5

Tags: ssl, tomcat, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have a tomcat server for which I needed a signed certificate. I generated a key using

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out sample_bfc_org.csr -keyout sample_bfc_org.key -subj "/C=BD/ST=Dhaka/L=Dhaka/O=Bangladesh Finance Corporatiobn/OU=IT/CN=sample.bfc.org"
```

and then generated a CSR and sent it to my company admin.

They gave me back a CER file with the signed certificate and certificate chain.

But when I import the certificate file in tomcat, I am getting the following error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connectionehls.bhbfc.org uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

My tomcat server.xml configuration is as follows:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" 
port="443"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
connectionTimeout="20000" 
acceptCount="100"
maxKeepAliveRequests="15"
SSLCACertificateFile="${catalina.base}/SSL/DigiCertCA.crt"
SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}/SSL/sample_bfc_org.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}/SSL/sample_bfc_org.key"
SSLPassword="123456"
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true" 
sslProtocol="TLS"
 />
```

But still, the error exists. What can I do to solve the following error?

```
This site can’t provide a secure connectionehls.bhbfc.org uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

Comment: Are you getting that error in your web browser when visiting your Tomcat site, during a sniffer capture session (eg, WireShark), or from the Apache web server logs?  Which browser (and version), Apache Tomcat server version(s), and OSes (and versions) are your web server and browser client running on?  You may need to define `SSLProtocol`, `SSLCipherSuite`, and/or `SSLHonorCipherOrder` settings in your Tomcat config file.  See [if this helps](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/)

Comment: I have defined SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" . But still the error exists.

Comment: You should enable debug logging on the `org.apache.tomcat.net` package as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36728281/11748454).

Comment: I have enabled debug logging on the org.apache.tomcat.net package as in this question. What  can I do next?